# Is it possible to specialize a template definition based on the existence of a nested typedef of a template type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, sfinae

I have a template, `template <typename T> class wrapper`, that I would like to specialize based on the existence of `typename T::context_type`. If `typename T::context_type` is declared, then the constructors and assignment operator overloads of the `wrapper<T>` instantiation should accept a mandatory `typename T::context_type` parameter. Additionally, `wrapper<T>` objects would store "context" in the member data. If `typename T::context_type` does not exist, then the constructors and assignment operator overloads of `wrapper<T>` would take one less parameter and there would be no additional data member.

Is this possible? Can I get the following code to compile without changing the definitions of `config1`, `config2`, and `main()`?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, bool context_type_defined = true>
class wrapper
{
public:
    typedef typename T::context_type context_type;

private:
    context_type ctx;

public:
    wrapper(context_type ctx_)
        : ctx(ctx_)
    {
        std::cout << "T::context_type exists." << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class wrapper<T, false>
{
public:
    wrapper() {
        std::cout << "T::context_type does not exist." << std::endl;
    }
};

class config1 {
public:
    typedef int context_type;
};

class config2 {
public:
};

int main()
{
    wrapper<config1> w1(0);
    wrapper<config2> w2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I have implemented such behavior in the past by using some metaprogramming tricks. The basic build blocks are:

`BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF`, to define a metafunction predicate that will evaluate to a true type if the argument is of class type and has a nested type with a given name (context_type in your case).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/has-xxx-trait-def.html

`Boost.EnableIf`, to define the specializations based on the previously defined trait.

http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/enable_if.html # See 3.1 Enabling template class specializations

---

Note that you may be able to get that behavior working directly with SFINAE, something like this may work:

```
template< typename T, typename Context = void >
class wrapper { ... }; // Base definition

template< typename T >
class wrapper< T, typename voif_mfn< typename T::context_type >::type > { ... }; // Specialization
```

However, I like the expressiveness of the solution based on traits and enable if.

Comment: You need to do something like `typename void_<typename T::context_type>::type` to make sure the specialization is valid *and* the second parameter matches the default parameter `void`.

Comment: @Luc Danton: My actual idea behind that was that the specialization won't get picked for types `T` that do not have an inner `context_type`, due to SFINAE.

Comment: The specialization will be invalid for those types that do not have the nested type, indeed, but if `T::context_type` is `int`, then the specialization is `wrappper<T, int>` and that won't match the primary template `wrapper<T, void>`, that's why I meant by "it won't match".

Comment: I placed `BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(context_type)` in `namespace detail`. It seems to work well for the template param to `boost::enable_if`. However, I think that I need to use `lazy_enable_if` for the inner `typedef`. Does `BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(context_type)` also output a "traits" type that can be used as the second template param to `lazy_enable_if`?

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien: You only need `lazy_enable_if` if you want to get the context_type in the same enabling operation. If so, the second argument to `enable_if` should simply be `detail::has_context_type< T >` with no `::type`.

Answer (score 4):

That's possible, and there are many ways to implement this. All of them should go back on some trait class `has_type` so that `has_type<T>::value` is true if the member typedef exists, and false otherwise. Let's assume we have this trait class already. Then here's one solution, using C++11 template aliases:

```
template <typename T, bool> class FooImpl
{
  // implement general case
};

template <typename T> class FooImpl<T, true>
{
  // implement specific case
};

template <typename T> using Foo = FooImpl<T, has_type<T>::value>;  // C++11 only
```

Now to make the typetrait:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_type
{
private:
    typedef char                      yes;
    typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;

    template<typename C> static yes test(typename C::context_type*);
    template<typename C> static no  test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

If you don't have C++11, or if you don't want to rewrite the entire class, you can make the distinction more fine-grained, e.g. by using `std::enable_if`, `std::conditional`, etc. Post a comment if you want some specific examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When C++11 is available for my project, then template aliases seems like the way to go. For now, though, I am restricted to C++03. Currently I am attempting to get @K-ballo's suggestion working, but this is proving to be difficult.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien You do not actually need the template alias to use this solution. You use the good-old inheritance trick: `template <typename T> struct Foo : FooImpl<T,has_type<T>::value > {};`

Comment: @David: But it'll be difficult making the correct constructors available in the new derived class. That's why I didn't just go with some inheritance from the start... I think the only way you can switch constructors individually is with `enable_if`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was just pointing out that the lack of template aliases is no reason to discard this solution. BTW, in the last paragraph  `std::enable_if` or `std::conditional` are both C++11 features, so if you do not have a C++11 compiler you would have to resort to `boost` for some of those features.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: `enable_if` and `conditional` are both oneliners that you could just write yourself in a crunch, or use TR1... but indeed, I sneaked that in there.

Answer (score 1):

Using [@K-ballo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575925/is-it-possible-to-specialize-a-template-definition-based-on-the-existence-of-a-ne/7576000#7576000), I wrote the following:

```
namespace detail {
BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(context_type)
}

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class wrapper
{
public:
    wrapper() {
        std::cout << "T::context_type does not exist." << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class wrapper<T, typename boost::enable_if<detail::has_context_type<T> >::type>
{
public:
    typedef typename T::context_type context_type;

private:
    context_type ctx;

public:
    wrapper(context_type ctx_)
        : ctx(ctx_)
    {
        std::cout << "T::context_type exists." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now, the sample code compiles and outputs:

```
T::context_type exists.
T::context_type does not exist.
```