# Traits for detecting final classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, sfinae

Is it possible to determine whether a class `T` is marked `final` at compile time? I've been trying to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576124/3234803)'s approach:

```
template<typename T>
struct sub {
    using type = struct : T {};
};

template<typename T>
struct is_final {
    using yes = char;
    using no = struct { char arr[2]; };

    template<typename U> static yes test(...);
    template<typename U> static no  test(typename sub<U>::type*);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof (test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof (yes);
};
```

But it doesn't work; `is_final<T>::value` is always `false`. It seems SFINAE doesn't work that way.

If it's impossible to implement this trait in C++11, how is it done in C++14 (`std::is_final`)? Is there some new language feature that enables this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>*The question was fundamentally changed after this answer, based on the information here. I'm not going to chase the question's evolution.*</sup>

Just use [`std::is_final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_final).

Comment: How is this implemented? Does it need language/compiler support?

Comment: @ZizhengTai: Yes, it's a piece of magic provided by the compiler, or implemented using compiler-specific means.

Comment: Umm...that's a weird one :-/

Comment: @ZizhengTai : In the realm of `<type_traits>` it isn't... ;-]